# how to call a method from another method using scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have two repository in scala. In one repo i have defined two methods. here from one method i need to call another method which code works is defined in another repository. I am stuck in calling the method. I am not sure whether the error is due to return type or some other code logic. So, i need help here as i am stuck in this problem.

In onerepo.scala =>

```
   override def getAll(implicit loginName: String): Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] = {
       doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery, "loginName" -> loginName)
       val output = methodtocallnextquery()   
       doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(methodtocallnextquery) // getting error here as cannot resolve with such signature
   }

   def methodtocallnextquery() = {
      if(map2Object.roleName != "" && map2Object.PersonID.isEmpty) {
         logger.error("user not autorised")
      } else {
         billingMonthCheckRepository.getrepo()
   }
```

In Second repo i have =>

```
   override val allQuery = s"""select * from table1"""

   def getrepo(): Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBilling]] = {
      doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery)
   }
```

// doquery is defined as:=>

```
  protected def doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(query: String, args: NamedParameter*) 
  = {  logger.debug(s"SQL: $query, args: $args")

  TimedFuture(actualityTimeout) {
  queryHandler.doQuery(query, args: _*) map { list =>
    // ignore mapping errors of specific rows
    list.flatten
  }
  } flatMap {
  case scala.util.Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
  case Failure(ex) if ex.isInstanceOf[SQLException] &&
    ex.getMessage == "The executeQuery method must return a result set." => 
  Future.successful(Nil)
  case Failure(fail)         =>
    Future.failed(fail)
```

Comment: What do you mean by repo? I think the error is about the param signature of `doQueryIgnoreRowError`. Can you provide the signature of `doQueryIgnoreRowError`? Your `methodtocallnextquery() ` returns `Any` from `if else`

Comment: @Orar, Repo is repository were i have written the sql query and some method. I have given what doqueryignorerowerror does over in the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your `methodtocallnextquery` function is not what you think it is I suspect. `logger.error` probably returns `Unit` (I'm guessing here, but that seems likely). If so the return type of that method is `Any`, which probably doesn't match the parameter type required for `doQueryIgnoreRowErrors`.